# SQL IN statement not checking properly?

Tags: sql, odbc, razorsql

I am working with a column/field from a table that has multiple "codes" or "ids" associated with it.

The table **afacctbal** has a column/field called **afacbbalid**, where the possibilities can be COST, PRN, or COLL.

What I am having trouble with is pulling the rows where COST is equal to 0 on the account.

I have tried a sub-queried SQL statement in the where clause, but returns a general error. Right now I am trying an IN statement but that doesn't seem to work either.

Here is what I've got:

```
select araccount.aracid as AccountID, arentity.arenst State, arentity.ARENNAME ClientName,
 afaccount.afaccurbal CurrentBal, afacctbal.afacbcurbal PrincipalBal,
  afacctbal.AFACBbalid
from araccount
 inner join arrelationship on araccount.aracid = arrelationship.arrelacid
 inner join arentity on arentity.arenid = arrelationship.ARRELENID
 inner join afaccount on afaccount.afacacctid = araccount.ARACID
 inner join afacctbal on afaccount.AFACKEY = afacctbal.AFACBACCTID
where afacctbal.afacbbalid in("COST",0)
    and afaccount.AFACRATEID = "MN100"
    and arentity.ARENST = "MN"
    and araccount.araclstdte > "2013-04-01"
order by afaccount.afaccurbal
```

The trouble lies within my where clause
Here:

```
where afacctbal.afacbbalid in("COST",0)
```

How would I check for COST and check to see if its equal to 0?

AFACCTBAL TABLLE
Used Values:
 afacbbalid -- balance id
 afacbcurbal -- balance amount per balance id.
afaccount Table 
Used Values:
 afaccurbal -- current balance

Comment: Please provide your table structure, sample data and desired results.

Comment: These tables are hundreds of fields long, is there anyway to just get an general idea of what direction to go?

Comment: the field afacbbalid has the possibilites of COST PRN COLL, each one has a value associated to it within the account, I just need to be able to pull the value. So something like afacbbalid.COST = ?? and display it

Comment: You don't need to supply the entire table -- just the relevant parts.  You say the `afacbbalid` is one of 3 values -- how could it be 0 then?  It's just easier when you provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: Sample data would be like Owen Smith, current balance $500.0, Principal balance 250, afacbbalid COST. that would be one row, where the 250 is the cost. the next row would be like Owen Smith, current balance $500, principal balance 200. afacbbalid INT, and so on where all the afacbbalid would add up to that curent balance.

Comment: Ill add in relevant parts of the table in an edit.

Comment: Hmmm -- what's wrong with just adding additional `where` criteria: `where afacctbal.afacbbalid = 'COST' and afacctbal.afacbcurbal = 0`?

Comment: the most recent answer posted has that same thing, my comment on it is my current dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `"COST"` which is string and then `0` which is an integer. So, you need to cast both in the datatype which column `afacctbal.afacbbalid` has.

Answer (score 0):

I think below query will work for your requirement -

```
select araccount.aracid as AccountID, arentity.arenst State, arentity.ARENNAME ClientName,
 afaccount.afaccurbal CurrentBal, afacctbal.afacbcurbal PrincipalBal,
  afacctbal.AFACBbalid
from araccount
 inner join arrelationship on araccount.aracid = arrelationship.arrelacid
 inner join arentity on arentity.arenid = arrelationship.ARRELENID
 inner join afaccount on afaccount.afacacctid = araccount.ARACID
 inner join afacctbal on afaccount.AFACKEY = afacctbal.AFACBACCTID
where ((afacctbal.afacbbalid ='COST'
    and afaccurbal.currentBal = 0) or 
     (afacctbal.afacbbalid ='PRN'
    and afaccurbal.currentBal > 0))
    and afaccount.AFACRATEID = "MN100"
    and arentity.ARENST = "MN"
    and araccount.araclstdte > "2013-04-01"
order by afaccount.afaccurbal
```

Comment: Yes that's what I have currently, But now I need to display accounts that still have a value within PRN under afacbbalid. My dilemma is I am unsure how to check for both PRN and COST at the same time with them being the same field.

Comment: am not exactly sure what u require but one more criteria can be added - `where afacctbal.afacbbalid ='COST' or afacctbal.afacbbalid ='PRN'`

Comment: Doing that would check if both of them are 0, I need a way to display the results where COST is 0 and PRN is greater than 0

Comment: criteria can be `where (afacctbal.afacbbalid ='COST'
    and afaccurbal.currentBal = 0) or (afacctbal.afacbbalid ='PRN'
    and afaccurbal.currentBal >0)`

Comment: If this resolves. Would you mind accepting latest edit as the answer.

Comment: Yes, currently trying it out. Execution time is crazy long on this PC